# Magento make an (OR) using collections

Tags: php, magento

I've a custom module with custom table, now, i'm trying to make something like a filter for that table,

```
Mage::getModel('comunity/news')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('title', array('like'=>'%'.$this->getRequest()->getParam('q').'%'));
```

with this is enough, and works perfect, but i need to add another field, is simple if you do like this

```
Mage::getModel('comunity/news')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('title', array('like'=>'%'.$this->getRequest()->getParam('q').'%'))  
           ->addFieldToFilter('shortdesc', array('like'=>'%'.$this->getRequest()->getParam('q').'%'));
```

it works to, but it make an (AND) and i want an (OR), i was lookin into Varien_Data_Collection_Db class, the function addFieldToFilter make a call to _getConditionSql where you can see something like this

```
        if (is_array($fieldName)) {
        foreach ($fieldName as $f) {
            $orSql = array();
            foreach ($condition as $orCondition) {
                $orSql[] = '('.$this->_getConditionSql($f[0], $f[1]).')';
            }
            $sql = '('. join(' or ', $orSql) .')';
        }
        return $sql;
    }
```

here an (OR) can be done, i've tried with

```
->addFieldToFilter(array (
                array('field'=>'title', 'like'=>'%'.$this->getRequest()->getParam('q').'%'),
                array('field'=>'shortdesc', 'like'=>'%'.$this->getRequest()->getParam('q').'%'),
            ))
```

but the query it makes is

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `uhma_comunidad_articulos` AS `main_table` WHERE (())
```

i need some help here
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you need to use `addAttributeToFilter` rather than `addFieldToFilter`.  Look in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection` and you'll see that the `addAttributeToFilter` method is testing for an array then adding as an `OR`:

```
if (is_array($attribute)) {
       $sqlArr = array();
       foreach ($attribute as $condition) {
           $sqlArr[] = $this->_getAttributeConditionSql($condition['attribute'], $condition, $joinType);
       }
        $conditionSql = '('.join(') OR (', $sqlArr).')';
        $this->getSelect()->where($conditionSql);
        return $this;
    }
```

`addFieldToFilter` in `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` is just adding the field to the `where` without testing for an array.

---

**EDIT**

Just noticed that you are using this on a Collection from your own custom module, not a Mage product collection.  That means that you'll need to implement the `addAttributeToFilter` method yourself in your `Collection.php` under `Model\mysql4\News\`.  Or, instead of `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`, make your Collection extend `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` which includes the implementation already.

HTH,
JD

Comment: actually addFieldToFilter does test for an array, read my post again

Comment: also, i can't use addAttributeToFilter, cuz i'm not using EAV, i'm just using a simple table, if i try to use addAttributeToFilter i'll get a call to undefined method

Comment: But if i extends my collection from Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract, will work for a single table??

Comment: My suggestion is that you edit Collection.php under YourNamespace\module\Model\mysql4\News\ to have the method addAttributeToFilter().  You can use Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::addAttributeToFilter() as an example.  That way you don't have to change the inheritance, but you get the benefit of the OR.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post can help: 
[Match as OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826474/magento-addfieldtofilter-two-fields-match-as-or-not-and/5988369#5988369).

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to do this with addFieldToFilter default functionality like this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    array('first_name','last_name'),
    array($post['firstName'],$post['lastName'])             
);
```

this is working when i print sql (this is just part from the whole statement being printed):

```
((first_name = 'r') OR (last_name = 't'))
```

now i am trying to understand how to use `'like'` instead of `=`.

hope it helps.