# OR and AND STATEMENT addAttributeToFilter magento

Tags: magento

I have created the following code.

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+1, date('y'));
$dateTomorrow = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
->addStoreFilter()
->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('neq' => ""))
->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $dateTomorrow), 1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))), 'left');
```

This is working fine. But what i want is to use the OR statement right now.
I thought i could fix it with this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),
array('attribute'=> 'anotherattribute','like' => 'value'),
));
```

But no succes. 
So my question is how to add OR statement to this.

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+1, date('y'));
$dateTomorrow = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
->addStoreFilter()
->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('neq' => ""))
->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $dateTomorrow), 1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))), 'left');
```

OR

Thank you.

Great,
Lex

Answer (score 3):

From Magento Wiki:

```
// Add OR condition:
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array(
        'attribute' => 'field_name',
        'in'        => array(1, 2, 3),
        ),
    array(
        'attribute' => 'date_field',
        'from'      => '2000-09-10',
        ),
    ));
```

So to write your query, which, as I understand it, is

```
"....WHERE special_price <> "" AND special_from_date <= '2012-07-02' AND (special_to_date >= '2012-07-03' OR special_to_date IS NULL)..."
```

you would use the following:

```
$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
->addStoreFilter()
->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('neq' => ""))
->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array(
        'attribute' => 'special_to_date',
        'date' => true,
        'from' => $dateTomorrow
    ),
    array(
        'attribute' => 'special_to_date',
        'null' => 1
    )
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the below links.

- [Using Collections in Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)
- [addAttributeToFilter and OR condition in Magento's Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301231/addattributetofilter-and-or-condition-in-magentos-collection)