# load product using custom attribute as well as if product qty is greater then 0 in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Am trying to do special offers to my magento shop.Actually that is easy but actually my scenario is differs from others.My scenario is,I must get the products based on custom attribute(date of sale) and as well as product qty must be greater than zero(Qty>0).I got the products using custom attribute like,

```
     <?php
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')- >getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addStoreFilter();


    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('date_sale', array('lt' => $todayDate));
     return $collection;?>
```

On this i got the products based on date of sale is lesser than today date.On that itself i must get products which qty is greater than 0.

give me some hopes guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the filter use another addAttributeToFiler('attribute code of inventory quantity',array('gt' => 0));

This acts as AND filter

You can check 'and'  and  'or' filter here [OR and AND STATEMENT addAttributeToFilter magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292208/or-and-and-statement-addattributetofilter-magento) asnd use according to requirement.

Comment: Thanks for replay sandeep....i cant find attribute code for qty...it is not there in eav_attribute table.

Comment: Use this
$collection->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
)
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 0));

Comment: hey thank sandeep..i forgot say on that day itself i solved that issue...thank u very much for ur reply

Comment: Gr8 news... Magento is little complex so would have to search a lot :)

Comment: thanks sandeep...while loading products like this,..its loading near to 500 products.. because of this my site is too slow..is this  possible how can i limit the products with in this statement?