# How to add OR condition in Magento Collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to fetch data from table by applying **OR** condition in **Collection**

I am using these lines of code

```
$collect  = Mage::getModel('storelocater/storelocater')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(array(
                array(

                    'attribute' => 'country',
                    'eq' => 'india'),

                array(

                    'attribute' => 'state',
                    'eq' => 'up')

            ));
echo $data = $collect->getSelect();
```

it prints the output 
    SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `storelocater` AS `main_table` WHERE ((**Array = ''**) OR (**Array = ''**))

i have also used **addAttributeToFilter** instead of **addFieldToFilter** but it returns fatal error

Comment: have you tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301231/addattributetofilter-and-or-condition-in-magentos-collection its working for me to give or condition in collection

Comment: yes i have tried this one. But addAtrributeToFilter() function only  works with EAV entities. It will not work for custom tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addAttributeToFilter` function will work only with EAV entities (like Customers, Products, Categories etc.). `addFieldToFilter` has slightly different syntax for **OR** operator:

```
$collect  = Mage::getModel('storelocater/storelocater')
    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(array('country','state'), array('india','up'));
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Slayer Birden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927404/slayer-birden) answer.

Also you can create more complicated queries like

```
    $rulesCollection
        ->addOrder('sort_order', Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
        ->addFieldToFilter(
            array('to_date', 'to_date'),
            array(array('gteq' => $now), array('null' => 'null')))
        ->addFieldToFilter(
            array('from_date', 'from_date'),
            array(array('lteq' => $now), array('null' => 'null')))
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1');
```

Constructed such SQL:

```
     SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `enterprise_targetrule` AS `main_table` 
     WHERE ((to_date >= '2013-03-21') OR (to_date IS NULL)) 
     AND ((from_date <= '2013-03-21') OR (from_date IS NULL)) 
     AND (is_active = '1') 
     ORDER BY sort_order ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
                array('attribute'=>'name', array('like' => '%'.$qry.'%')),
                array('attribute'=>'sku',  array('like' => '%'.$qry.'%'))));
for search by name and search by sku
```

Answer (score 0):

For 
$collections = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', array('in' => $sellerIncrementIds))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => ['pending','pending_seller_confirmation']]);