# Magento - Collection OR AND filter

Tags: magento

I want to select products collection with condition "A or (B and C)" by using AddAttributeToFilter, but I have no idea..

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('xyz/abc')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                    array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
                    array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),
                    array('attribute'=> 'anotherattribute','like' => 'value'),
                )
            );
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
```

Transnational will be look like

```
WHERE ((someattribute LIKE 'value') OR (otherattribute LIKE 'value') OR (anotherattribute LIKE 'value')) and status=1
```

You can also visit this link for more info

[Magento addFieldToFilter: Two fields, match as OR, not AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826474/magento-addfieldtofilter-two-fields-match-as-or-not-and/7851884#7851884)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need "A or (B and C)", not "(A or B) and C"