# Magento multiple addFieldToFilter?

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to add multiple `addFieldToFilter` to my `filter`.

This is what I currently have:

```
$cards = Mage::getModel('giftcards/giftcards')->getCollection()
               ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order->getId());
$cards = Mage::getModel('giftcards/giftcards')->getCollection()
               ->AddFieldToFilter('gc_sent', false);
```

Is this the right way to do this? Or should I be doing it another way?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826474/magento-addfieldtofilter-two-fields-match-as-or-not-and <- something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple filter like below

```
$cards = Mage::getModel('giftcards/giftcards')->getCollection()
              ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order->getId())
              ->addFieldToFilter('gc_sent', false)
              ->addFieldToFilter('other_field', 'value');
```